# $ U $ is self-adjoint then $\|U\|= sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |<Ux,x>|.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

let H be hilbert space and let $U\in L(H).$
show that if U is self-adjoint then $$\|u\|= sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |<Ux,x>|.$$
I showed that $ sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |<Ux,x>|\leq \|U\|.$
But can you help me to find the other direction please thank you.

Comment: $||Ux||^2=\langle Ux,Ux\rangle =\langle U^{*}Ux,x\rangle\leq \sup \langle U^{*}Ux,x\rangle \leq ||U^{*}||\sup \langle Ux,x\rangle=||U||\sup \langle Ux,x\rangle$ maybe let helpfull

Comment: yeah since $\|U\|= sup \|Ux\|$ so $\|U\| \leq sup \langle Ux,x \rangle$

Comment: @weymarandres why should $\sup \langle U^*Ux,x\rangle \le \|U^*\| \sup \langle Ux,x\rangle$ be true??